# Sort weightly a dataframe according to two columns

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and i want to order it based in two columns. With `df.sort_values(['col1', 'col2'], ascending=False)` it sorts first with the col1 and then with col2. However what I wanted to do is to sort giving the same importance to both columns which is the sort was done taking into account both columns instead of one first and then the other one. How can I do this ?

Edit: col1 is float and represents a percentage and col2 is also a float but its not a percentage

Comment: Combine both columns into one, based on your understanding of "same importance," and then sort by the new column.

Comment: what the dtypes of the columns?

Comment: I can't combine both into only one column, both of them are float values but one is a percentage and the other is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ?

```
df['Rank']=df.col1.rank()+df.col2.rank()
df.sort_values('Rank',ascending=False).drop('Rank',axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much !

P.S. Because i wanted the result in the same frame I just had to put df=df.sort_values('Rank',ascending=False).drop('Rank',axis=1)